# Fonts and calibration in math mode

Tags: math-mode, subscripts

Anyone have any ideas on how to obtain the small `+` in the subscripts, shorter `\overline` on the `\mathbb{N}` and the fat `\verts` on the semi norm on the bottom as seen in the following notation?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! The link you've provided contains dozens and dozens of pages, with hundreds of mathematical expressions. Please be a bit more specific as to which page (or pages) you are contemplating.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`) or hit Ctrl+K.

Comment: I was intending to link to page xi.

Comment: I cannot load that page from Google Books. Could you maybe provide a screenshot of thecharacter in question?

Answer (score 4):

Here are some possible solutions.

Use `\smallerplus` for the reduced size plus and `\shorteroverline{<symbol>}` if you need a shorter overline.

For `\fatnorm` the syntax is

- `\fatnorm*{<formula>}` for the "automatically extensible version"
- `\fatnorm[<size>]{<formula>}` for the manually specified size; the default is "nothing", but `<size>` can also be `\big`, `\Big`, `\bigg` or `\Bigg`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

%% service macros
\newcommand{\shorteroverline}[1]{%
  {\mkern1mu\overline{\mkern-1mu#1\mkern-1mu}\mkern1mu}}
\newcommand{\smallerplus}{\mathchoice
  {\scriptstyle+}
  {\scriptscriptstyle+}
  {\scriptscriptstyle+}
  {\scriptscriptstyle+}
}

%% N with shorter bar and smaller plus
\newcommand{\Nbarplus}{\shorteroverline{\mathbb{N}}_{\smallerplus}}

%% fat norm
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@fatnormbar}{\vrule\@width 1.2\p@}
\newcommand{\fatnorm}{\@ifstar\@xfatnorm\@fatnorm}
\newcommand{\@xfatnorm}[1]{%
  \left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
  \@fatnormbar
  #1
  \@fatnormbar
  \right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
}
\newcommand\@fatnorm[2][]{%
  \mathopen{\vphantom{#1|}\mkern2mu\@fatnormbar\mkern2mu}
  #2
  \mathclose{\vphantom{#1|}\mkern2mu\@fatnormbar\mkern2mu}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$\Nbarplus$

$\displaystyle\fatnorm*{\frac{1}{2}}
\fatnorm{v}\fatnorm[\big]{v}\fatnorm[\Big]{v}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Change the figure in `\@fatnormbar` if you want a different width for the fat norm bars.

Answer (score 1):

As you haven't attached a MWE, I will give you this in complete:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\minus}{{}^{-}}
\newcommand{\plus}{{}^{+}}

\newcommand{\bigvert}{\mathop{\rule{1ex}{1em}}}

\makeatletter
\newsavebox\myboxA
\newsavebox\myboxB
\newlength\mylenA

\newcommand*\xoverline[2][0.75]{%
    \sbox{\myboxA}{$\m@th#2$}%
    \setbox\myboxB\null% Phantom box
    \ht\myboxB=\ht\myboxA%
    \dp\myboxB=\dp\myboxA%
    \wd\myboxB=#1\wd\myboxA% Scale phantom
    \sbox\myboxB{$\m@th\overline{\copy\myboxB}$}%  Overlined phantom
    \setlength\mylenA{\the\wd\myboxA}%   calc width diff
    \addtolength\mylenA{-\the\wd\myboxB}%
    \ifdim\wd\myboxB<\wd\myboxA%
       \rlap{\hskip 0.5\mylenA\usebox\myboxB}{\usebox\myboxA}%
    \else
        \hskip -0.5\mylenA\rlap{\usebox\myboxA}{\hskip 0.5\mylenA\usebox\myboxB}%
    \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\mathds{R}_\mathrm{\plus}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\xoverline{\mathds{N}}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\bigvert \cdot \bigvert {}_\infty
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Hope this suits you (although it might be not a very compact solution).

Comment: Would appreciate a feedback, is this what you wanted?